# Can I have a Table with primary Key which is a Foreign Key in more than one Table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-design, class-diagram

I want to create a database for a group feature in my Flutter Application and I want the group to consist of administrators with different roles like Moderator, Secretary, etc...

| Group Table |  |
| --- | --- |
| groupId | `int not null primary key` |
| roleId | `int foreign key` |
| firstName | `string (50)` |
| lastName | `string (50)` |
| email | `string (80)` |
| address | `string (100)` |

| Role Table |  |
| --- | --- |
| roleId | `int not null primary key` |
| roleType | `string (20)` |
| groupId | `int foreign key` |

| Admin Table |  |
| --- | --- |
| adminId | `int not null primary key` |
| roleId | `int foreing key` |
| groupId | `int foreign key` |

Can I have `groupId` as a Foreign Key in `Role_Table` and also have `groupId` as foreign key in the `Admin_Table`?

Comment: Yes of course you can

Comment: Contradictory scheme. You must have the scheme similar to this: Groups, Roles which refers to Groups, and Admins which refers to Roles (and through it - to Groups). Opposite references may produce wrong situation, for example group G1 refers to role R1 which refers to group G2... or admin A1 refers to role R1 directly and to role R2 via group G1...

Comment: *I want the group to consist of administrators with different roles like Moderator, Secretary* This means M:N link which needs in intermediate adjacency table.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please only tag a single RDBMS.

Comment: To me, "group" is a very misleading name for a table of users. I suspect your schema is flawed but only you know what the tables represent and what entities you are attempting to model in your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not fully clear to me what you want to achieve with the group.  But to answer your question: it is  possible to reference the same table as foreign key in different tables. So yes, you can use `groupId` as foreign key in `Role_Table` and `Admin_Table`.

However there are some potential issues here:  `Admin_Table` has its own `roleId`.  This is either an undesired redundancy, if your code has to keep both consistent,  or a design that is potentially ambiguous,  since a given `adminId` could be associated directly with one `groupId`, and indirectly via the role table to another `groupId`.  Thera are some situations where this triangular relationship is needed on purpose, but are you sure in your case?

There is a potentially bigger issue: In `Group_Table`, a `groupId` (primary key) is associated to a `roleId` (foreign key).  This means that there is only one role possible for a given group.  At the same time, in the `Role_Table` a `roleId` (primary key) is associated to a `groupId` (foreign key).  This means that either there is a one-to-one relationship between groups and roles (that needs to be kept in sync), or roles and groups form a complex interleaved hierarchy.